# How to store a xml file with true/false value in a mysql database

Tags: mysql, xml, load-data-infile

I have a xml file which contains rows like

```html
<row Id="50720" UserId="24115" Name="Teacher" Date="2011-04-29T03:17:22.257" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
<row Id="50717" UserId="902" Name="c++" Date="2011-04-29T03:00:17.067" Class="3" TagBased="True" />
```

I want store the data of this xml file into my mysql databse.
My current create table syntax is

```
create table Badges(
Id int,
UserId int,
Name nvarchar (50),
Date datetime,
Class tinyint,
TagBased bit
);
```

The sql statement to import the xml file is as follows:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/media/anurag/Learning/iit_hyderabad/Sem_3/dataset /Badges.xml'
INTO TABLE Badges(Id, UserId, Name, Date, Class,TagBased);
```

But **TagBased** column is not able to be stored properly as mysql does not directly recognize False as 0 and True as 1. 
This above query is storing 1 for all the False as well as True fields in the database.

Can you please help me with the right fix for the query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use variables within the `load xml` statement to convert the text true/false to a boolean true/false, which are the same as 1/0.

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/media/anurag/Learning/iit_hyderabad/Sem_3/dataset /Badges.xml'
INTO TABLE Badges(Id, UserId, Name, Date, Class,@var)
SET TagBased=(@var = 'True');
```